# I could not run the sudo npm i -g expo cli command after software update on mac

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After installing **macOS big Sur Version 11.4**, I couldn't run the sudo npm i -g expo cli to download the files from DoneWithIt. What can I do? Here are the codes:

npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

changed 832 packages, and audited 833 packages in 47s

28 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

5 low severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: changed 832 packages, and audited 833 packages in 26s

28 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

5 low severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for

Comment: Edit question to include the error.

Comment: there you go @JohnNyingi

Comment: I see no errors, only warnings. changed 832 packages.

Comment: What can I do then?